# Python : PyUSB can't access usb device

Tags: python, pyusb

I am trying to read an usb bar code reader from my python script, via the https://github.com/pyusb/pyusb library.

```
import usb.core
import usb.util
VENDOR_ID = 8208
PRODUCT_ID = 30264


dev = usb.core.find(idVendor=VENDOR_ID,

                       idProduct=PRODUCT_ID)
dev.set_configuration()
cfg = dev.get_active_configuration()
intf = cfg[(0,0)]
ep = usb.util.find_descriptor(
    intf,
    # match the first OUT endpoint
    custom_match = \
    lambda e: \
        usb.util.endpoint_direction(e.bEndpointAddress) == \
        usb.util.ENDPOINT_IN)
data    = ep.read(ep.wMaxPacketSize, 8000000)
```

Unfortunately, this leads to a `"USBError: [Errno 13] Access denied (insufficient permissions)"` issue.

I tried to run the script as a `sudo`, but it didn't help. The script work fine on my Ubuntu laptop, but I am now trying to move it to Mac OS. One of the differences is that I do have a "detach_kernel" before hand on Linux, but this function make a fail with `"not implemented on this OS"` error with Mac Os...

Comment: From https://github.com/pyusb/pyusb: **PyUSB is being developed and tested on Linux and Windows**. Note MacOS isn't tested. Have you tried running a shell wrapper instead? (On Ubuntu I would have tried `subprocess.run('lsusb'.split())` for example)

Comment: I didn't see that, thanks for the hint !

Comment: What kind of device is this? It sounds as if macOS grabs the device because it has a specific driver for it.